# What's the point of boost::multi_index_container::index<Tag>::type?

Tags: c++, boost, typedef, multi-index

If you have a `boost::multi_index_container< >` with multiple indices, there are obviously multiple ways to iterate over it - each index defines a way. For instance, if you have an index with tag `T`, you can iterate from `container.get<T>().begin()` to `container.get<T>().end()`.

If you try to do so in a for-loop (and do not have C++0x `auto`), the type of the iterator is `multi_index_container<...>::index<T>::type::iterator`. Now `index<T>::type` will be boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index or something structurally equivalent. E.g. it will provide an `iterator` typedef, and a `begin()` method.

Now my question is, since `multi_index_container< >::index<T>` seems to exist only to typedef `index<T>::type`, and `index<T>::type` has known members, why doesn't `index<T>` typedef those members ? This would allow you to write `multi_index_container<...>::index<T>::iterator`.

Similarly, why is `multi_index_container< >::index_iterator<T>` not an iterator? `multi_index_container< >::index_iterator<T>::type` is, but why did Boost choose an embedded typedef ? Again the `::type` seems to add only clutter.

Comment: I had to look this up in our code because I didn't know about the ::type.  It seems that we have typedef'ed them all so it doesn't show up in the implementation.  So no answer from me: I never had a problem with it so I never bothered understanding why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think it was just an oversight. Especially with such a non-trivial library such as `boost::multi_index_container<T>`. I often find code I've written that aren't bugs *per se*, but felt that I could've been done better in retrospect.